# Mongo db sharded "the collection's metadata lock is taken" issue coming very frequently

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am seeing this warning in mongoS log consistently for one collection.

```
[conn96] warning: splitChunk failed - cmd: { splitChunk: "ibeat20150105.dgrpCount", keyPattern: { articleId: 1, host: 1 }, min: { articleId: MinKey, host: MinKey }, max: { articleId: MaxKey, host: MaxKey }, from: "shard0000", splitKeys: [ { articleId: "01a12144225c646875aeea79990432", host: "xyz.com" } ], shardId: "ibeat20150105.dgrpCount-articleId_MinKeyhost_MinKey", configdb: "x.x.x.x:27017,x.x.x.x:27017,x.x.x.x:27017" } result: { who: { _id: "ibeat20150105.dgrpCount", state: 1, who: "ibeatdb61:27017:1420207410:680478249:conn105:432206596", ts: ObjectId('54aa4f1c253720e5ba254fde'), process: "ibeatdb61:27017:1420207410:680478249", when: new Date(1420447516889), why: "split-{ articleId: MinKey, host: MinKey }" }, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "the collection's metadata lock is taken" }
```

This is coming continuously for one collection.
Also when i checked the data distribution this whole data is on one shard only for this particular collection.
I check lock with id: balancer it seems to be working fine. as i did not get a time for which it has locked indefinitely.
I have 5 mongos servers running in my application

This is creating load on my primary shard which is impacting write operations. 
Could you please help me.

Comment: Please post the output of the following to the question (from a mongos): `use config; db.locks.find();` - the warning you are seeing basically implies that the meta data for the collection in question is locked, so we need to see where that lock is and what is holding it.  Occasionally locks can go stale, but there is logic in MongoDB to force them eventually (it can take time), at which point the collection can split and then be balanced (currently there is only one chunk because splits are failing and hence no balancing is possible)

Comment: Hi Adam there are 5725 entries in locks collection currently. I checked with balancer id in lock collection and got one point that some time this lock was taken for almost 2 hours. I am running 5 mongos servers. Could you please tell me if i need to search some specific locks in this collection

Comment: The balancer is actually not responsible for splits (it moves chunks after they are split to address imbalances), the mongos processes are what attempt to split chunks based on the amount of writes (inserts/updates) they see to a given chunk. Let me put together the query you need to run to get the specific locks for this collection, in the mean time I will add an interim answer with some steps to try to address the immediate issue

Answer (score 1):

There are two things which take a meta data lock on a collection - the balancer (to move a chunk) and a mongos (to split a chunk).  Now, sometimes you will get this warning (it is just that, a warning) if, for example, a mongos attempts to split while another mongos is already performing a split.  Or, it might be that the balancer is moving chunks and so the split cannot get a lock for that reason.

In either case, the chunk will usually get split eventually and things will settle down, but you have indicated that is not happening.  If the balancer is running constantly then you may want to re-evaluate your shard key choice and whether you need to [pre-split](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19672302/1148648) etc. to alleviate the imbalances you are creating.

In any case, one thing that you can do to give the mongos a better chance to be able to split without an error is to temporarily disable the balancer to see if stopping it allows the splits to happen.  This is covered as part of the more detailed and complicated procedure I am about to cover for the more extreme case.

That extreme case would involve some sort of issue with stale locks.  As mentioned in the comments, this is intended as a break-fix type of intervention to get that particular collection split.  It is a lot of work, and it is not really for beginners.  The lock that is blocking the splits should expire eventually on its own eventually, but you may not have the time to wait for that to happen.  To force the issue, we need to basically do the following:

- Reduce contention for the meta data lock (balancer, and splits)
- Connect to a mongos, split the chunk on the collection manually
- Manually move some chunks for the collection onto other shards (manual balancing)
- Restore normal balancing and splitting

**Note:** this will require you to restart mongos processes if you want to be absolutely sure.  That will usually mean down time for your application and some errors getting thrown back to your app when you do the restarts. For this reason, and for general safety I would recommend doing this at a low traffic or scheduled maintenance time. For reference in terms of how splitting happens, see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62855/6441).

First, [turn off the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.stopBalancer/#sh.stopBalancer):

```
sh.stopBalancer()
```

The command will wait for balancing to complete before returning, so this may take some time if the balancer is currently actively balancing chunks.  To verify the state of the balancer you can use [`sh.getBalancerState()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.getBalancerState/) and [`sh.isBalancerRunning()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.isBalancerRunning/#sh.isBalancerRunning). This is also the piece you should try initially as mentioned at the start of the answer.

Next, restart all of your current mongos processes with the [--noAutoSplit option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption--noAutoSplit). By doing these two things you have essentially guaranteed that:

1. Nothing else will be trying to make meta data changes on this cluster (which will allow you to do so manually without error)
2. If there are any remaining locks blocking you from taking action in the config.locks collection, they are now definitely stale and can be removed if necessary.

Next, you need to manually split the chunk on the collection that has been failing.  The easiest command to do so is [splitFind()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.splitFind/#sh.splitFind).  It will basically work with any valid query for you since you only have one (Min to Max) chunk:

```
sh.splitFind( "ibeat20150105.dgrpCount", { articleId: $SOMEVALUE, host: $SOMEVALUE } )
```

This will split the chunk in two, and you can repeat for the resulting chunks (with different values to target different chunks) to get to a decent number - I would aim for at least the same number of chunks as you have shards so that you can move data to them, but basically the only real limit is that the new chunks must be less than you max chunk size (64MB by default) in order to be moved successfully.  If you know your current approximate data size (from `db.collection.stats()`) for example, then it should be easy to figure out how many chunks you are going to need.

If you encounter a similar error regarding locks being taken **and you are sure you have disabled the balancer and splitting on all mongos processes** then you can remove the entries from the `config.locks` collection (because they must be stale) manually and retry.  As long as you run the remove command from a `mongos` and not directly on the config servers, this should be safe enough.

Once you have your split and appropriately sized chunks you can move them from shard0000 with the [`moveChunk()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.moveChunk/) command, something like this (to move to the theoretical shard0001):

```
sh.moveChunk("ibeat20150105.dgrpCount", { articleId: $SOMEVALUE, host: $SOMEVALUE }, "shard0001")
```

Once your chunks have been moved to your satisfaction, you can restart your mongos processes without the `--noAutoSplit` option, returning them to normal.  When that is complete, re-enable normal balancing with [`sh.startBalancer()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.startBalancer/).

Comment: Hi Adam this seems to be quite complex process. I hvae one more question if you can give some guidance on it. We can set chunk size limit for a DB. But chunk has a limit of 250000 documents per chunk. My chunk size is 250 MB which varies the number of document in each collections. So normally some of my collections crosses this limit of maximum documents. Could you please suggest how should i do the calculation in this case.

Comment: There is no point in setting a maximum chunk size of anything over ~200MB if your documents in that chunk are less than 1024 bytes in size.  If they are, then the chunk will always split at the 250k document mark anyway and the size setting is basically meaningless.  There are very few reasons to alter the setting from the default of 64MB so I am not sure why you have done so here.  In any case, it will mean longer chunk migrations and may be contributing to your issues, I would recommend reverting to the default size

Comment: Sure Adam that will make sense i will test it and will update on it.

Comment: HI Adam i tried that but still the balancer is taking too much time to release locks my writes have become extremely slow now we are having size at 64 MB which is default size and we took a complete restart of our mongo cluster

Comment: My primary shard mongod is continuously showing 1000% cpu uses

Comment: balancer move failed: { chunkTooBig: true, estimatedChunkSize: 141493800, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "chunk too big to move" } from: shard0000 to: secondset chunk:  min: { articleId: "45789345", host: "xyz.com" } max: { articleId: "45790988", host: "xyz" }
2015-01-08T15:26:46.229+0530 [Balancer] forcing a split because migrate failed for size reasons

Comment: The too big message is expected if you lower your chunk size - you will have a large portion of chunks that exceed the new size as a result and will need to be split. You can either put the chunk size back up (average doc size x 250000 should cover most based on your previous comments) or look to address the issues manually. I can't say for sure without in depth troubleshooting that really isn't possible here but I suspect the root issue here is shard key related

Comment: I check some of my collections have average object size of below 500 but some has even 1 KB average size of object is 700 so what do u suggest to have chunk size based on average db object size (700) or with the size of (1 KB)

Comment: with Shard key i have compound shard key which i select with two field one is articleId which have almost 40K different values alphanumeric and the second is host name which has 20 different values. so key is like articleId_1Host_1 i get almost 8 million records in my DB with this key reason for chioossing this shard key is that i am having a very even distribution almost with it and i craete daily db which has all these collection so for last 6 months it was all fine but it started happening 5 days back only.

Comment: to troubleshoot this fully and get to a root cause I would need to see logs from the mongos processes, the mongod processes, a copy of the config database and would need to get an idea of your traffic pattern for inserts, how article IDs are generated.  Basically this is a full blown support or consulting case and I don't think it will be possible to solve it on stack exchange.  The procedure I have outlined above will work, but you will need to apply it judiciously to your particular cluster (perhaps programmatically). The only other option is to revert the settings and wait for the balancer